# How can I crontably reboot a Linux host upon network failure?

Tags: networking, cron

I have a personal [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) host, connected to a public/sharing Wi-Fi [AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) (not under my control).

Sometimes, it would have a network issue, and I am very sure, only restarting the network service would not work. The only way is to reboot it.

My plan is to add a crontab, to test the network connection. If it fails, then reboot the computer.

If I manually run the auto_reboot.sh, it does reboot, when a *[ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29)* test fail.
But running from crontab, it is not working:)

Here is my crontab entry

```
crontab -l
* * * * * /root/loadrc/transmissionrc/auto_reboot.sh
```

#### File */root/loadrc/transmissionrc/auto_reboot.sh*

```
#!/bin/zsh

/root/loadrc/networkrc/ping.sh
rc=$?

if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "say The internet is back up."
else
    reboot
fi
```

#### File */root/loadrc/networkrc/ping.sh*

```
#!/bin/zsh
((count = 10))                           # Maximum number to try.

while [[ $count -ne 0 ]] ; do
    ping -c 1 8.8.8.8                    # Try once.
    rc=$?
    if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then
        ((count = 1))                    # If okay, flag loop exit.
    else
        sleep 1                          # Minimise network storm.
    fi
    ((count = count - 1))                # So we don't go forever.
done

exit $rc
```

I add some logs, and deliberately bring down the Wi-Fi interface:

```
watch ifconfig wlan0 down
```

```
transmissionrc/auto_reboot.sh
#!/bin/zsh

echo "" > /root/loadrc/crontab.log

/root/loadrc/networkrc/ping.sh
rc=$?

if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "say The internet is back up."
else
    reboot
fi
```

```
networkrc/ping.sh
#!/bin/zsh
((count = 10))                           # Maximum number to try.


while [[ $count -ne 0 ]] ; do
    /usr/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log 2>&1
    echo "step --> 2" >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log
    rc=$?

    if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then
        echo "step --> 3" >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log
        ((count = 1))                    # If okay, flag loop exit.
    else
        echo "step --> 4" >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log
        sleep 1                          # Minimise network storm.
    fi
    ((count = count - 1))                # So we don't go forever.
done

exit $rc
```

#### File */root/loadrc/crontab.log*

```
/usr/bin/ping: connect: Network is unreachable
step --> 2
step --> 3
```

which means, in the crontab mode, even the ping test fail, the return code is still zero.

So the question comes to: how can I test the network connection in crontab mode?

Comment: it looks like an x and y issue, what is the original issue you trying to solve?

Comment: Re *"a personal Ubuntu host"*: Wouldn't that make it off-topic?

Comment: I wouldn't use `cron` for that, but `watchdog`, which is specifically designed to reboot the local machine if some condition fails, and allows running custom commands as checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three thoughts on possible solutions to your issue:

##### 1. You said:

`If I manually run the auto_reboot.sh, it does reboot, when a ping test fail. But running from crontab, it is not working:)`

Usually, when a command runs properly in your interactive shell (from the CLI), but fails to run properly under `cron` it is due to a difference in the **environment**; e.g. `cron` has a different PATH than you do from your interactive shell. *Typically*, the `cron` environment is: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. *Any script* you run run under `cron` will not be able to find executables that are not on the PATH.

As an aside, you can check the `cron` environment on your system by simply running `env` using your `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /my/cronlog/location/mycronenvironment.txt 2>&1
```

In your `auto_reboot.sh`, you failed to use a *full path specifications* for `reboot`. As `reboot` is typically found in `/sbin/reboot`, and `/sbin` *may not be* in the PATH used by `cron`, this is a potential problem.

**Consequently**, I will suggest that you verify the environment (PATH) used by `cron`, and double-check all of your commands are either: 1) on the `cron` PATH, or 2) use a *full path specification*.

##### 2. You run everything out of the `/root` directory

Ordinarily, `/root` isn't used for *user* scripts. Perhaps you are using `sudo`? Or, perhaps you have done an `su` to become root? If this is the case, I would *comment* that this is not *best practice*, even though it can still work. I feel *best practice* is to use `sudo` from your *user* account for any privilege escalation you need.

Without trying to be pedantic, I'd like to say that the `root` account has a `crontab` that runs independently of any *user* `crontab`. Also, the `root crontab` does not require `sudo` be used - everything done in the `root crontab` is done with `root` privileges.

All of that said, I see the call to `reboot` in your script - a command that *requires* root privileges to run. This will work as you've written it **only** when used in the `root crontab`. Your question did not indicate whether or not you are using `su` or `sudo`, and so I went through this in an effort to make two points clear:

> 1. If your `cron` job requires `root` privileges, it *may be* best to run that job from the `root crontab`. The alternative is to use `sudo` in a `user crontab` which is potentially awkward if authentication is required for `sudo` - as is often the case.

> 2. The `root crontab` may be accessed from a regular user account simply by using `sudo crontab -e`; i.e. one is not required to `su` to `root` to access the `root crontab`.

##### 3. You may have a logical error in your script

As pointed out in [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1088714/515728), it is not clear that you can rely on the value of `rc` from your `ping.sh` script as a condition for `reboot`. Unfortunately, whether or not this is an issue is masked by what seems to be two different versions of the `ping.sh` script in your question - it is unclear whether you are using the first version:

```
#!/bin/zsh
((count = 10))                           # Maximum number to try.

while [[ $count -ne 0 ]] ; do
    ping -c 1 8.8.8.8                    # Try once.
    rc=$?
```

or the second version:

```
#!/bin/zsh
((count = 10))                           # Maximum number to try.


while [[ $count -ne 0 ]] ; do
    /usr/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log 2>&1
    echo "step --> 2" >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log
    rc=$?
```

Strictly as my personal choice, I would favor combining the code from these two scripts (`ping.sh` and `auto_reboot.sh`) into a single script because it seems more straightforward to me, but you may have good reasons for doing it this way, and there's no reason it won't work if done correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes, I found the reason, I need to use full path of the reboot command.
I isolated the logic to a ping.sh, is for better reuse, maybe other of my scripts might need it.
it is my personal headless linux just for fun, so, I always logged in as root, the cron and scripts are all run as root.
one follow up question: if I(root) not logged in, will the root cron doing its job?
what I want is a cron, even no users(including root) is logged in, it would still regularly run, and check the network status, and reboot if needed.
@seamus

Comment: @huangyingw: *"`one follow up question: if I(root) not logged in, will the root cron doing its job? `"* Yes - `cron` is a *daemon* that runs in the background with no user intervention required; its sole purpose is to run jobs even when the user is not logged in.

Comment: great to hear, thanks. @seamus

Comment: @huangyingw: You're welcome - and please don't forget to [vote on any answers you find *useful*, and *select* an answer](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) if appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

```
/usr/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log 2>&1 
echo "step --> 2" >> /root/loadrc/crontab.log  
rc=$?
```

I think this checks the exit code of the `echo` command while your logic needs  the exit code of the `ping` command.

Comment: yes, bug in my echo, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @huangyingw So, can you update your question to correct that?